# The best way to handle schedule of local notification in Phonegap?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm coding phonegap app that included local notification. First of all I use plugin from

> https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/0.7

which is easy to use.

my app has 5 times a day to notify user (example : 5.00 AM, 12.00 PM, 4.00 PM, 8.00 PM and 9.00 PM)

[image]

If you seen in the picture, my app allows user choose which time they prefer to notify. If user turn **5.00 AM** on, the app will notify at 5.00 AM otherwise it won't.

My question is what is the best way to handle notification like this, should I need to schedule all notification when users open the app or another way to suggest me?

Moreover, how to make it repeat everyday? note that the time of each day will be different.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule on app startup or just add a button to your UI.

For repetition, your plugin may support that feature but afaik, you should specify each notification separately. I would schedule a whole month or week each time the app starts (or when the schedule button is pressed). You can never know when is the next time your user will open your app, so it's better to schedule as much as you can when you have the chance. If you are a nice developer, you can ask your user for repetition and scheduling as well..